# jQuery validate non english letters

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I need a custom validation method for jquery.validate plugin, which allows me to type only letter and special characters like üõöä. 
Right now I have a custom method, which allows me to  type only letters without special characters.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) 
{
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z ]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a letters only.");
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at writing a new regex?

Comment: I'm not familiar with regular expressions))

Comment: At SO you're expected to have a basic familiarity with the topic you're asking about and to have shown an attempt at solving it yourself.   Thanks.

Comment: No, I have found it here, on stackoverflow also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test for BOTH english AND non-english letters you can use this regex:

```
([^\x00-\x7F]|[a-zA-Z])
```

It will test for letters that are NOT in the range of a-zA-Z or letters in that range.
This is the within the jQuery validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) 
{
    return this.optional(element) || /^([^\x00-\x7F]|[a-zA-Z])+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a letters only.");
```

Another option - if you want to use a specific set of chars to allowed:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) 
{
    return this.optional(element) || /^([a-zA-ZÆÐƎƏƐƔĲŊŒẞÞǷȜæðǝəɛɣĳŋœĸſßþƿȝĄƁÇĐƊĘĦĮƘŁØƠŞȘŢȚŦŲƯY̨Ƴąɓçđɗęħįƙłøơşșţțŧųưy̨ƴÁÀÂÄǍĂĀÃÅǺĄÆǼǢƁĆĊĈČÇĎḌĐƊÐÉÈĖÊËĚĔĒĘẸƎƏƐĠĜǦĞĢƔáàâäǎăāãåǻąæǽǣɓćċĉčçďḍđɗðéèėêëěĕēęẹǝəɛġĝǧğģɣĤḤĦIÍÌİÎÏǏĬĪĨĮỊĲĴĶƘĹĻŁĽĿNŃN̈ŇÑŅŊÓÒÔÖǑŎŌÕŐỌØǾƠŒĥḥħıíìiîïǐĭīĩįịĳĵķƙĸĺļłľŀŉńn̈ňñņŋóòôöǒŏōõőọøǿơœŔŘŖŚŜŠŞȘṢẞŤŢṬŦÞÚÙÛÜǓŬŪŨŰŮŲỤƯẂẀŴẄǷÝỲŶŸȲỸƳŹŻŽẒŕřŗſśŝšşșṣßťţṭŧþúùûüǔŭūũűůųụưẃẁŵẅƿýỳŷÿȳỹƴźżžẓ])+$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a letters only.");
```